# 17.10 netplan config with bridge

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Ok I just did a new install with 17.10 and trying to get my KVM up and running and can't figure out how to config the network.  Here's what my old interfaces file looked like

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp10s0 
iface enp10s0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enp10s0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

This has worked for years, but not I can't get my KVM instance to start because it's telling me br0 doesn't exist.  I've tried a few things I've found with netplan, but nothing has made a difference.

Answer (score 9):

your configuration could look like this:

```yaml
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
         enp10s0:
            dhcp4: false
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [enp10s0]
            dhcp4: true
            parameters:
                stp: false
                forward-delay: 0
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  One more question.  What is now the correct way to restart the network?  /etc/init.d/networking is no longer available.

Comment: to apply changes you made in /etc/netplan/*.yaml, you can run `netplan apply` - more inf o at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan

Comment: I'm using 18.04 LTS, and the above YAML yields:    $ netplan apply
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 0 column 8: expected mapping

Comment: I think the indentation for this code block is fouled up; it looks like everything after the first line should be indented. Can someone with more familiarity with netplan + YAML confirm?

Comment: does STP off by default in Netplan?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my config that's very similar to above. This worked for me with 18.04 LTS:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
     enp5s0f0:
        dhcp4: true
     enp5s0f1:
        dhcp4: true
  bridges:
     br0:
       interfaces: [enp5s0f0]
       dhcp4: true
       optional: true
```

Comment: Is your KVM host machine on enp5s0f1? I added your "bridges" stanza verbatim (but changed to eno1 for my server) to my netplan config, rebooted, and the host machine had no connectivity.

Comment: I see a problem here.   You have DHCP configured port enp5s0f0 and also made it a member of your bridge.  The bridge should get the DHCP session because it's port br0 is the one that gets the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a yaml that I just completed on mine to get bridge working. This was a headache to do for me, because I am terrible with Linux. This is on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, but I am a bit confused, because the .yaml is "50-cloud-init.yaml", but I didn't do the cloud install, just the normal server. Maybe that is normal, but it didn't seem to match up with the naming convention I was finding in tutorials. Side note, while this DOES work on my server, I am having a HELL of a time with KVM. The machine SHOWS running in virsh, but it sits there with the CPU pegged, isn't pingable, but doesn't give errors. In 14.04, it JUST WORKED. I am tempted to downgrade.

After you completed the .yaml changes, you can verify them, then apply them with the following commands:

sudo netplan --debug generate

sudo netplan apply

Note any errors you get start from the top left corner, including commented out lines. starting with Line 0, and column 0.

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      switchports:
        # all cards on second PCI bus;
        # unconfigured by themselves, will be added to br0 below
        match:
          name: enp1*
          mtu: 4400
    bridges:
      # the key name is the name for virtual (created) interfaces; 
      # no match: and set-name: allowed
      br0:
        # IDs of the components; switchports expands into multiple interfaces
        interfaces: [switchports]
        addresses: [172.16.5.20/24]
        gateway4: 172.16.5.1
        nameservers:
          addresses: [172.16.5.2]
        parameters:
          forward-delay: 0
          stp: false
```